# export a chart as excel or pdf in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, charts, oracle-apex, apexcharts

I have a region with type 'chart' and this region get data with a query from database and show as area chart
want to have a button that when click on it , the chart data downloaded as  pdf or excel

I tried to use report queries but I cant have a print server

Answer (score 1):

A simple option (doesn't require anything additional) is to

- create a button (its label is e.g. "Print")
- create a dynamic action which fires when the button is pressed
- dynamic action executes JavaScript code, this:

  ```
   window.print()
  ```
- run the page, push the "Print" button

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: tanx for commenting but I want to  have a report  style thing to download , what is you suggested is just print the entire page

Comment: In toolbar you have option to export csv file https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/#csv

Comment: @PatrykLaszuk, *your* Apexcharts is very different from Oracle Application Express' charts (which is the *topic* here).